# Why do the Delphi and FreePascal compilers handle 0-based and x-based static arrays differently?

Tags: delphi, freepascal, lazarus

```
program test;

uses
  sysutils;

const
  BUFLEN = 20;

var
  Buf0: array[0..BUFLEN-1] of char;
  Buf1: array[1..BUFLEN] of char;
  s: string;

begin
    // Fillchar...
    // StrPLCopy...

    SetString(s, Buf1, Length(Buf1));
    // Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 2: Got "Array[1..20] Of Char", expected "PChar"

    SetString(s, Buf0, Length(Buf0));
    // compiles ok
end.
```

In C/C++, we use array names as pointers very often. In Delphi, we can also implement this like the example above.

Though, using the `Buf1` array in FreePascal's [`SetString()`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/setstring.html) causes an error, while the `Buf0` array works just fine. An array's base index shouldn't matter, right?

Is there any documentation that **justifies** this behaviour?

Tested in FPC 3.0.4 and Delphi 10.3.

Comment: It's documented [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/String_Types_(Delphi)#Using_Pointers.2C_Arrays.2C_and_String_Constants) : *".. Zero-based character arrays are compatible with PChar and PWideChar. ... "*.

Comment: In addition to what @HeartWare says in his answer, it's maybe worth bearing in mind that traditional Pascal supports arrays of entirely symbolic elements with no numeric indices.

Comment: Alternatively this would "work", too: `SetString( s, PChar(@Buf1[1]), Length( Buf1 ) );`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the definition you link to, the 2nd argument can be one of the following types:

```
  Buf: PAnsiChar;
  Buf: PWideChar;
  Buf: PChar;
  Buf: PUnicodeChar;
  Buf: PChar;
  Buf: PWideChar;
  Buf: PChar;
```

If you remove the duplicates / aliases, you get the following possibilities:

```
  Buf: PAnsiChar;
  Buf: PWideChar;
  Buf: PUnicodeChar;
```

In the {$X+} state, there is a built-in type compatibility between:

```
PAnsiChar <-> ARRAY[0..nn] OF AnsiChar
PWideChar <-> ARRAY[0..nn] OF WideChar
PUnicodeChar <-> ARRAY[0..nn] OF UnicodeChar
```

As you can see above, all the Char arrays that are compatible with PChar-types all have a lower index of 0. That's just how the compiler type compatibility works. The reason for this is that it this type compatibility mainly is for easier conversion of C(++) code, and C(++) doesn't have the ability to specify a lower limit of (ordinary) arrays - they are always 0.

So the same is done in Delphi / FreePascal in order to remain (as much as possible) compatible with C(++).

Comment: "specify a lower limit" as in: with which ordinal an array starts. While C(++) always starts with `0` a Delphi/Pascal array can also perfectly start with i.e. `42` or, like Vassilis did, with `1`.